# Jquery/JS - Create Objects Dynamically For Each Div Within

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

**COMMENT FROM 2 YEARS LATER**

This is one of my old posts. Basically, I wanted to create **variables** with **dynamic names** via functions with a **string parameter** and that the variables is stored **globally** outside the scope of the function and **can be accessed later by any other functions**.

But because I don't know the term "global" and so, I was having a hard time explaining.

Enjoy!

---

Backstory: So I wanted to build a JS library for my own interface webpages. The result is, if I add  `<div class="window SOMENAME"></div>` within my `div#Environment`. The webpage will generate a working window. That I have done.

But **some JS objects must be declared** for this to work

```
window["window" + winname].bmaxheight = $(cwindow).height();
```

, So if I add a new window "`.window.s`"

```
<div class="window s">
    <!--Each window(`div`) REQUIRES a `.window` class and a unique name(here, ".s"), there WILL be ONLY 2 classes.-->
    ...
</div>
```

, I had to **hand type** the following `object` declarations.

```
windows = new Object();
windows.bmaxwidth = 0;
windows.bmaxheight = 0;
windows.bmaxpositionx = 0;
windows.bmaxpositiony = 0;
//Each new window(`div`) REQUIRES a new object named with the string "window" and the name(here, "s") appended.
```

So how do you generate new JS `object`s **dynamically** for each new **manual input** of `div`(window) in a loop?

Meaning, if I just hand typed in the

```
<div class="window SOMENAME"></div>
```

, it will **automatically declare the objects**:

```
windowSOMENAME = new Object();
windowSOMENAME.bmaxwidth = 0;
windowSOMENAME.bmaxheight = 0;
windowSOMENAME.bmaxpositionx = 0;
windowSOMENAME.bmaxpositiony = 0;
```

Concept:

```
function loop() {
   1.check all divs within $("#Environment") and make an array of names for new objects(above are "s" and "SOMENAME")(no problem)
   2.generate new objects in a loop ("window" + "NAME" and declare bmaxwidth, bmaxheight...)
}
```

**Please comment if more information is needed.**

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code generator

Comment: Why not using the index of divs to separate your object?

Comment: @jantimon Sorry if I typed poorly, I don't know how to explain myself maybe. But I am not asking for a complete code, I just wanted a line, which will solve my problem. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could use the other syntax to access the variables. Because global variables are stored under `window`

```
window["SOMENAME"] = new Object();
```

It would work also with a variable inside

```
var k = "SOMENAME"
window[k] = new Object();
```

---

**EDIT FROM 2 YEARS LATER**

A better approach is to create some empty objects initially and globally, then later populate them with the respective "dynamic variables". In this way, data are organized better rather than dumping everything under `window`.

Example:

```
var fruitBasket = {};

function addFruit(name, fruitProperties) {
    /*Maybe some logics to determine whether the fruit already
      exists in the basket to make this function more useful
      than simply fruitBasket.SOMENAME = {SOMEOBJECT}*/
    fruitBasket[name] = fruitProperties;
}

function getFruit(name) {
    return fruitBasket[name];
}

addFruit("apple", {
    color: "red",
    growsOnTree: true
});

getFruit("apple");
```

Or you may even want to organize it better like this:

```
var fruitBasket = {
    storedFruits: {},
    addFruit: function(...) {...},
    getFruit: function(...) {...}
};
```

Comment: I just came across my old question today. Basically what I wanted to do was to create a "global" variable that can be accessed through their "string" name. But I didn't know the concept of "global", I didn't use the word and that created the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add a new CSS class to the HTML you can do so using the following (jQuery)

`var cssClass = $('<style>body { background: blue; }</style>')
$('html > head').append(cssClass);`

This will create the cssClass and append it to the head tag.

dynamically creating elements is achieved in the same manner `$(<<html>>)`.

you should consider **creating a plugin** in jQuery to do this task. it would streamline the whole process.

Comment: I am very sorry! My question misled you :'( I wanted to create JS objects, not CSS classes, but thanks for helping!!!

Comment: Sorry, but no. I wanted to know how to dynamically generate this line `windowSOMENAME = new Object();` for every window `class="window SOMENAME"` within my containing div.